# Is it possible to use INSERT INTO and then SELECT later?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver

I'm trying to insert values into a database, but one of the values is a primary key from another table. I have two tables, address and User. User has the primary key of address as a foreign key. I am trying to insert values the customer inserts into the database, but User is not getting the addressid(Primary Key of address). The main purpose of this is so I can have address as a separate table and pull the address when needed to the User table. I am using dreamweaver and phpmyadmin to do this.

I was thinking maybe do:

```
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO User (name, email, addressid) VALUES ('%".GetSQLValueString($_POST['Name'], "text"). "%', '%".GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text")."%' SELECT addressid FROM address";
```

But this is giving me an error of

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't'%', '%'t'%' SELECT addressid FROM address' at line 1
```

If someone could please help, that would be great. Sorry I have never been taught SQL nor PHP so I don't know much code.

Comment: how about wrapping them in a stored procedure?

Comment: there's `insert into ... select from`, but you can NOT use a `values()` section in such a query. the values are provided exclusively by the `select from`. you'll have to run two separate queries. one to insert your fixed values, then another one to the insert/select

Comment: @今草顿웃 how do i do that?

Comment: And @MarcB it gets the values fine, and inserts those, but it will not get the addressid

Comment: @MarcB: Surely one can use `INSERT ... SELECT` with literal values in the select list?  e.g. `INSERT INTO User (name, email, addressid) SELECT 'eggyal', 'eggy@al.com', addressid FROM address WHERE ...`?  Or even use a subquery within the `VALUES()` clause, e.g. `INSERT INTO User (name, email, addressid) VALUES ('eggyal', 'eggy@al.com', (SELECT addressid FROM address WHERE ...))`?

Comment: yes, that works, but you can't have `insert into table values (xxxx) select from`. the `values (...)` portion is not permitted in such a query.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta do 2 queries.
If you use an incremental primary, you can catch the last inserted id to build your SELECT query.

Example:
http://php.net/mysql_insert_id

Comment: so do i use `INSERT INTO` for that?

Comment: or `UPDATE` to update the User table with the new value?

Comment: First you insert the address, then get the last inserted id and insert the user.

Comment: I am now using `$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO User (name, email, addressid) VALUES (%s, %s, '%".$query_Record."%')",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"));` query_record holds the last inserted from a previous page when addressid was entered. i am then calling `global $query_record` from the other page and then using the above code

Comment: I am getting the following error: ``Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`addressid`) REFERENCES `address` (`addressid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)``

Comment: If the page changes you'll need to keep it in SESSION or remodel the way you're doing it